# how to Increase limit the total number of items displayed in list per page

Tags: list

I have a list with 1000 items persent currently. As of now it show 30 items per page due to which I have to navigate to many pages. Can anyone help me with steps how i can increase limit to 100 items in list per page so that it would be easier for us. 
Also how I can edit 1000 items at once in easier way in one page, can i use datasheet view to edit 1000 items in single page?

Answer (score 4):

Lists display content/items via views. Select a view or create a new view and change the item limit settings from 30 to 1000.  However, realize that when you increase the item limit, the browser will now needs to download more content per page and this will impact how quickly the page is ready for use.

To edit multiple items more quickly you can try the datasheet view.